# XmlPullParser: How can I find out what the START_TAG is?

Tags: android, xml, parsing

I have a program that parses XML that can be in several different formats.

Each type has a different starting tag.

My parsing code starts like this:

```
        XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();
        parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
        parser.setInput(in, null);
        parser.nextTag();
        while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
            if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                continue;
            }
```

Is there any way I can find out what the START tag is?

I know I can just open the file and read & compare, then close it, re-open it and then parse it, but is it possible to just find out what XmlPullParser found as the START tag?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured it out.

After the first nextTag(), you can call getName() to get the start tag:

```
XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();
        parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
        parser.setInput(in, null);
        parser.nextTag();
        String startTag = parse.getTag();
        while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
            if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                continue;
            }
```